# Font name not found while generating thumnail image from pdf

Tags: java, pdf, thumbnails, pdfbox

I am trying to generate images from text pdf pages.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

following line gives me an error while converting pdf page to image :

```
BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage();
```

Stack Trace :

```
java.awt.FontFormatException: Font name not found
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:528)
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:162)
    at sun.font.FontManager.createFont2D(FontManager.java:2474)
    at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:570)
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:896)
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.drawString(PDTrueTypeFont.java:361)
    at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.showCharacter(PageDrawer.java:160)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:409)
    at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowText.process(ShowText.java:64)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:452)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:174)
    at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:104)
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:657)
    at com.demo.controller.web.ProcessTransactionController.getSliderData(ProcessTransactionController.java:182)
    at com.demo.controller.web.ProcessTransactionController.processSelectedTransactions(ProcessTransactionController.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    .
    .
    .
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.pdfbox.exceptions.WrappedIOException: Font name not found
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.drawString(PDTrueTypeFont.java:382)
    at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.showCharacter(PageDrawer.java:160)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:409)
    at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowText.process(ShowText.java:64)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:452)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:174)
    at org.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:104)
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:657)
    at com.demo.controller.web.ProcessTransactionController.getSliderData(ProcessTransactionController.java:182)
    at com.demo.controller.web.ProcessTransactionController.processSelectedTransactions(ProcessTransactionController.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:185)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.demo.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.demo.filter.gzip.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke..
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: And can you share a PDF with which that error can be reproduced?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : I am using pdfbox 0.7.3

Comment: The current versions are 1.8.10 and 2.0 RC2. 0.7.3. is from 2006. Get a current version here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Its an old web-app. I have to achive the thing using pdfbox 0.7.3

Comment: Then you'll have to analyze the source code of 0.7.3 and change it yourself